# android sdk is too old

Tags: c#, xamarin, bundle, adt

I am installing xamarin on visual studio and I see an error:

> Something went wrong
>   The installed android sdk is too old.version 24.34 or newer is required.

Screen shot of error.
[image: Screen shot of error]

Where can I download latest adt bundle (with adb.exe) ?

Comment: First, out everything into the question itself. Don't leave info in comments or "answer". It is Stack Overflow, not a forum. Second, Android SDK Manager has its settings (like menu items under Tools). You should refer to Google Android documentation to learn how to use them properly. This is not what SO should tell you.

Comment: Actually, this is a perfectly valid question.  I have Android SDK Manager, and since upgrading Xamarin, it tells me it requires "v25.1.3" of the Android SDK, but it's not *listed* in Android SDK Manager.   So, I also want to know where I can actually find this non-existant SDK.....

Comment: Btw, here's a link to the instructions (written by a Xamarin guy) will takes you through the steps required to get around this issue:  http://motzcod.es/post/150380059392/preparing-machines-for-xamarin-cycle

Answer (score 1):

You can update your Android SDK by using the Android SDK manager. Either look under Tools inside Visual Studio menu bar or use the windows key and start typing "Android SDK..." you than should find the SDK Manager.